# How to sort JSON data in a column in ascending order in angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a JSON response that has teamId from 1 to 43

```
[{"teamId":"1"},{"teamId":"2"},{"teamId":"3"},{"teamId":"4"},{"teamId":"5"},{"teamId":"6"},{"teamId":"7"},{"teamId":"8"},{"teamId":"9"},{"teamId":"10"},{"teamId":"11"},{"teamId":"12"},{"teamId":"13"},{"teamId":"14"},{"teamId":"15"},{"teamId":"16"},{"teamId":"17"},{"teamId":"18"},{"teamId":"19"},{"teamId":"20"},{"teamId":"21"},{"teamId":"22"},{"teamId":"23"},{"teamId":"24"},{"teamId":"25"},{"teamId":"26"},{"teamId":"27"},{"teamId":"28"},{"teamId":"29"},{"teamId":"30"},{"teamId":"31"},{"teamId":"32"},{"teamId":"33"},{"teamId":"34"},{"teamId":"35"},{"teamId":"36"},{"teamId":"37"},{"teamId":"38"},{"teamId":"39"},{"teamId":"40"},{"teamId":"41"},{"teamId":"42"},{"teamId":"43"}]
```

from the api the numbers are well sorted, but when I try to display them on angular 10 , they end up mixed up, have tried to sort the data using on sort method, but no luck,

what I have so far, component.ts

```
onSort({column, direction}: SortEvent) {
    this.sort = {column, direction};
    if (direction === '') {
      this.teams = this.teams;
    } else {
      this.teams = [...this.teams].sort((a, b) => {
        const res = compare(a[column], b[column]);
        return direction === 'asc' ? res : -res;
      });
    }
  }
```

in my component.html

```
  <tr>
                <th [sortable]="'teamId'" (sort)="onSort($event)"> Team Code
    </tr>
```

what could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a compare function which you should then pass to the `array.sort()` function, where you compare the values of the object to each other.

```js
array = [
    { teamId: '1' },
    { teamId: '5' },
    { teamId: '6' },
    { teamId: '7' },
    { teamId: '34' },
    { teamId: '35' },
    { teamId: '36' },
    { teamId: '37' },
    { teamId: '38' }
]

  sortArray(array: { teamId: string; }[]) {
    array.sort(this.compare);
  }

  compare( a, b ) {
    return a.teamId - b.teamId
  }
```

I created a stackblitz where you can test the functionality: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bt2zfw?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

For more insight on how the Array.sort method works see here: [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: and incase I want the data to load sorted without using a button?

Comment: You said that you get your data from an api, so you could just call this method in your response and then assign the result to your array. Or did I miss something here?